# keep getting a 404 on routing with params

Tags: express, mern

Im doing a mern tutorial on freecodecamp and I have run into an issue that is driving me nuts.

I have a route which is localhost:5000/exercises/1234

however I keep getting a 404 on that route.

If someone could point out the error if would be appreciated.

I have a server file:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const exerciseRouter = require("./routes/exercises");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users");

require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;

mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Mongo DB database connection established successfully ");
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/exercises", exerciseRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is running on port ${port} `);
});
```

and the route is defined here in an exercise.js file:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Exercise = require("../models/exercise.model");
  router.route("/:id").get((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    Exercise.findById(req.params.id)
      .then((exercise) => res.json(exercise))
      .catch((err) => res.status(400).json(`Error ${req.params}`));
  });
```

When i run this in the browser I get a 404 and not even the console log is run. Im really not sure why it isnt working.

Answer (score 1):

Ah disregard this issue, i did an idiotic mistake.  I had the method get inside another method (which isnt apparent in the above question).

Note to myself and others make sure your route aren't nested by accident in another route! lol